# Cannot display SHAP text visualization in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, shap

I am trying to build a dashboard of my NLP project. So I am using a BERT model for the predictions, the SHAP package for the visualization and Streamlit for creating  dashboard:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_cla)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name_cla)
labels = ['1- Tarife','2- Dateneingabe','3- Bestätigungsmail','4- Kundenbetreuung','5- Aufwand vom Vergleich bis Abschluss',
          '6- After-sales Wechselprozess','7 - Werbung/VX Kommunikation','8 - Sonstiges','9 - Nicht auswertbar']

def f(x):
    tv = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(v, padding='max_length', max_length=128, truncation=True) for v in x])
    attention_mask = (tv!=0).type(torch.int64)
    outputs = model(tv,attention_mask=attention_mask)[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
    scores = (np.exp(outputs).T / np.exp(outputs).sum(-1)).T
    val = sp.special.logit(scores)
    return val

text = ['This is just a test']

# build an explainer using a token masker
explainer = shap.Explainer(f, tokenizer, output_names=labels)

shap_values = explainer(text, fixed_context=1)

shap.plots.text(shap_values)
```

The code works fine in my jupyter notebook but when I am trying to execute this as .py file with streamlit nothing happens. It neither displays anything nor throwing an error. My console just returns this while execution:

> <IPython.core.display.HTML object> >

How can I display my graph in streamlit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be visualized with `Streamlit Components` and latest `SHAP v0.36+` (which define a new `getjs` method), to plot `JS SHAP plots`

> (some plots like `summary_plot` are actually `Matplotlib` and can be plotted with `st.pyplot`)

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

def st_shap(plot, height=None):
    shap_html = f"<head>{shap.getjs()}</head><body>{plot.html()}</body>"
    components.html(shap_html, height=height)

st_shap(shap.plots.text(shap_values),400)
```

Find more detailed discussion on Visualizing Shap in `streamlit` here - [Display SHAP diagrams with Streamlit](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/display-shap-diagrams-with-streamlit/1029/8)

Comment: I don't know why but I always get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'

Comment: you've actually got `None` html. Is it the same code you added in the question?

Comment: yes the exact same one. I also updated shap for that-

Comment: Can you check if you are really generating any visualization from the data??

Comment: When I execute the code (shap.plots.text(shap_values)) in my jupyter notebook it genrates the expected plot. SO I guess I am generating one...or am I missing anything?

Comment: in the jupyter notebook, is it normal plot or `html`?

Comment: html I think...it is interactive

Comment: Try this, `st.pyplot(shap.plots.text(shap_values))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240131/discussion-between-pluviophile-and-soulwreckedyouth).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output of the shap plot and render it with `components.html`

```
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
from IPython.utils import capture

def st_plot_text_shap(shap_val, height=None)
    InteractiveShell().instance()
    with capture.capture_output() as cap: 
        shap.plots.text(shap_val)
    components.html(cap.outputs[1].data['text/html'], height=height scrolling=True)
```